# After creating login and registration page HTML and CSS how to take user input and save to data base?

Tags: python, html, css, django, web

I'm currently making a website and have created both the HTML and CSS for both the registration and login Pages - I'm wanting to use Django to save the information, I'm just a bit confused on how  to take the user input (using my html inputs) and then transferring them to the Django data base.
I'm very new to web development as you can tell - I'm just trying to take it one step at a time.

```css
/* 
This is the style sheet for the Registration Page only
 */
body {
    background-color: rgba(255,0,0,0.65);
}

h2 {
    color: white;
    font-family: optima;
    font-size: 300%;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-variant: small-caps;
    line-height: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    z-index: 0;
    margin-top: -50px;
}
h3 {
    color: white;
    font-family: Helvetica;
    font-size: 250%;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-variant: small-caps;
    margin-top: 50px;
}

#rectangle{
    top: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    width:450px;
    height:550px;
    background:rgba(43, 43, 43, 1);
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    border-radius: 15px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index:-5;
    top: 550px;
}
img {
    opacity: 0.8;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
div {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 0;
}
label{

color:white;
    font-family:Helvetica ;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
select{
    font-family:Helvetica ;
    background-color: lightgrey;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
    padding: 50;



}
span {
    color:white;
    font-family:Helvetica ;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}
p {
    font-size: 10px;
    color:lightgrey;
    font-family:Helvetica ;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}

input[type=text]:focus{
    font-family:Helvetica ;
    background-color: lightgrey;
}

input[type=text]{
    font-family:Helvetica ;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}

input[type=password]{
    font-family:Helvetica ;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}
input[type=password]:focus{
    font-family:Helvetica ;
    background-color: lightgrey;
}
input[type=Vpassword]{
    font-family:Helvetica ;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}

input[type=checkbox]{
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
}
input[type=button]{
    font-family:Helvetica ;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 50px;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <!-- Tab title for the window and importing stylesheet -->
        <title>SEAS Course Planner</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="registrationstyle.css"/>
    </head>
<body>
    <!-- WKU image file, specify width in center/top of page -->
    <img src="output-onlinepngtools.png" width="200" height="100">
    <div>

        <!-- Headers for webpage and then login title -->

        <h2>SEAS COURSE PLANNER</h2>
        <h3>Create Account</h3>

        <!-- Background Rectangle -->
        <div id="rectangle"></div>

    </div>      

    <form>

        <!-- Drop down menu to select what account type -->

        <label for="usertype">Account Type:</label>

        <select name="usertype" id="usertype">

            <option value="Student">Student</option>

            <option value="Admin">Admin</option>

        </select>


        <!-- textboxes for username password, and password verification -->

        <div>

            <span>Create a New User Name:</span>

                <!-- Side note to enter in Student ID if Student-->

                <p> <em>(If student, Use Student ID Number)</em> </p>

        </div>

        <input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="New Username"><br>


        <span>Create a Password:</span>


            <input type="password" id="myInput" name="password" placeholder="New Password"><br>

            <input type="password" id="myInput2" name="Verify Password" placeholder="Verify Password"><br>

        <!-- checkbox for user to check if they would like to see their password in the textbox -->

        <span>Show Passwords:</span>

        <label for="showpassword" style="word-wrap:break-word"> 

            <input id="showpassword" type="checkbox" onclick="showPassword();showVPassword()"

        </label>



        <!-- two buttons (not yet connected to corresponding webpages) for login and create account -->
        <input type="button" value="Create Account"><br>

    </form>

    <!-- javascript to hide password AND verification password unless checkbox is checked -->
    <script>
        function showPassword() {
            var x = document.getElementById("myInput");
            if (x.type === "password") {
                x.type = "text";
            } else {
                x.type = "password";
            }
        }
        function showVPassword() {
            var x = document.getElementById("myInput2");
            if (x.type === "password") {
                x.type = "text";
            } else {
                x.type = "password";
            }
        }
    </script>
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the Django authentication system https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/default/ or you can do a scaffold which will generate all that is needed to create the form and save into database.